# Snap to curve in Corel Painter 2023

Tags: brush, bezier-curve, corel-painter

I'm new to Corel Painter 2023.
In this old video [Brush tracking and snap to curves](https://youtu.be/7X2H0c4f14o?t=202) about Corel Painter X3 the guy presents a feature called 'snap to curve'. (The video is timestamped.) I would need the same thing in Corel Painter 2023 or at least a good possible approximation of it, if it exists. So far I cannot find it, although I'm not a seasoned user.
Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Have you tried checking the Painter help documentation? [I found this](https://product.corel.com/help/Painter/540111162/index.html?app=Corel-Painter&lang=en#/l2TOC98?sub=1328377).

Comment: That's it! I thought there's gotta be a tool for that, I just couldn't find it.